# Limit and scale the size of text in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, centering, cashapelayer

I have a `UITextField` with two `CAShapeLayers`. I want to have my text always centered and limited (in size) to the inner, white circle.

How can I limit the size of the text within that white circle, best with a padding, but also make the text always fill that space? The second part prob has something to do with a scaling factor which sets the text font size smaller, if there is more text.

Here is my MWE:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .darkGray

        let size:CGFloat = 300.0
        let centerPoint:CGFloat = 200.0

        let valueLabel = UITextField()
        valueLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        valueLabel.contentVerticalAlignment = .center
        valueLabel.textAlignment = .center
        valueLabel.text = "300"
        valueLabel.textColor = .black

        valueLabel.font = UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 100)
        valueLabel.bounds = CGRect(x:0.0, y:0.0, width:size, height:size)
        valueLabel.center = CGPoint(x:centerPoint, y:centerPoint)

        let redCircle:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        redCircle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: valueLabel.bounds).cgPath
        redCircle.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        redCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        redCircle.lineWidth = 10

        valueLabel.layer.addSublayer(redCircle)

        let whiteCircle:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let tmpRect = CGRect(x:valueLabel.bounds.origin.x,y:valueLabel.bounds.origin.x,width:valueLabel.bounds.width-80.0,height:valueLabel.bounds.height-80.0)
        whiteCircle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: tmpRect).cgPath
        whiteCircle.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        whiteCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        whiteCircle.lineWidth = 10
        let posX = valueLabel.bounds.midX - (size-80.0)/2.0
        let posY = valueLabel.bounds.midY - (size-80.0)/2.0
        whiteCircle.position = CGPoint(x:posX, y:posY)
        valueLabel.layer.addSublayer(whiteCircle)

        self.view.addSubview(valueLabel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose I can suggest using UITextView, it has native support for that via NSTextContainer. [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nstextcontainer/1444569-exclusionpaths)

```
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [..] // array of UIBezierPaths
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
valueLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
valueLabel.minimumFontSize = 0.5
```

I hope that would be useful for you.

Comment: minimumFontSize was deprecated iOS 7

Comment: BTW to set a limit for the minimum font size, you would need to set the minimum scale to be applied to the font size setting the minimumScaleFactor property iOS 7+